# How do I limit the number of replacements when using gsub?

Tags: ruby, gsub

How do you limit the number of replacements made by String#gsub in Ruby?

In PHP this can be easy done with preg_replace which takes a parameter for limiting replacements, but I can't figure out how to do this in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gsub replaces all occurences.

You can try String#sub

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185

Comment: Damn! I looked through the String functions to find something else then gsub, and why didn't I notice sub!? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a counter and decrement that within a gsub loop.

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
count = 5
p str.gsub(/a/){if count.zero? then $& else count -= 1; 'x' end}
# => "xxxxxaaaaa"
```

Comment: Works, but it's ugly. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
# The following is so that the variable new_string exists in this scope, 
# not just within the block
new_string = str 
5.times do 
  new_string = new_string.sub('a', 'x')
end
```

Comment: I see. This is nicer. But, when the replacement string matches the regex, for e.g. `sub('a', 'cat')`, you need to modify the regex, for example, `sub(/\Ga/, 'cat')`. Or, is this correct?

Comment: Actually, `\G` didn't seem to work for `sub`. It get's reset each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.split` method, which takes a limit, with a `join` with the replacement:

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
n=5
puts str.split(/a/,n+1).join("e")
# eeeeeaaaaa
```

This works when the replacement string would match the regex since the split is done prior to the replacement:

```
# use +1 more than desired replacements...
'aaaaaaaaaa'.split(/a/,6).join(' cat ')
" cat  cat  cat  cat  cat aaaaa"
```

You can also use `gsub` with a block and count and ternary:

```
n=4  
'aaaaaaaaaa'.gsub(/a/){|m| (n-=1) >= 0 ? " cat " : m}
" cat  cat  cat  cat aaaaaa"
```

You can also use the regex index method with a `.times` loop:

```
5.times{str[/a/]='e'}
"eeeeeaaaaa"
```

But you can't use a replacement that matches the regex for this last one:

```
5.times{str[/a/]=" cat "}
# " c c c c cat t t t t aaaaaaaaa"
```