# How do I limit the number of times a block is called?

Tags: ruby, block

In [How do I limit the number of replacements when using gsub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009653/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-replacements-when-using-gsub/6010980#6010980), someone suggested the following way to do a limited number of substitutions:

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
count = 5
p str.gsub(/a/){if count.zero? then $& else count -= 1; 'x' end}
# => "xxxxxaaaaa"
```

It works, but the code mixes up how many times to substitute (5) with what the substitution should be ("x" if there should be a substitution, `$&` otherwise). Is it possible to seperate the two out?

(If it's too hard to seperate the two things out in this scenario, but it can be done in some other scenarios, post that as an answer)

Comment: I was interested in that. I thought of using something like `MatchData#begin`, `MatchData#length`, `MatchData#end`, `String#match(regex, position)`, or somehow use `/\G/` with `gsub`, but did not fully work that out. Maybe someone can elaborate an idea along this line, or along a completely different perspective. Looking forward for answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just extracting the replacement as an argument and encapsulating the counter by having the block close over it inside a method?

```
str = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

def replacements(replacement, limit)
    count = limit
    lambda { |original| if count.zero? then original else count -= 1; replacement end }
end

p str.gsub(/a/, &replacements("x", 5))
```

You can make it even more general by using a block for the replacement:

```
def limit(n, &block)
    count = n
    lambda do |original|
        if count.zero? then original else count -= 1; block.call(original) end
    end
end
```

Now you can do stuff like

```
p str.gsub(/a/, &limit(5) { "x" })
p str.gsub(/a/, &limit(5, &:upcase))
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe you can go a step further and do `gsub_with_limit(regex, limit, optional_replacement, &optional_block_replacement)`? I'm not sure.

Comment: @sawa: Sure, but notice this can be used with other methods than `gsub`. For example, `[*1..10].map(&limit(5) { |x| 2*x })`.

Comment: I didn't realize that. That's cool. But somehow, the syntax is a bit strange.

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` will call the block exactly as often as the regex matches the string. The only way to prevent that is to call `break` in the block, however that will also keep `gsub` from producing a meaningful return value.

So no, unless you call break in the block (which prevents any further code in the yielding method from running and thus prevents the method from returning anything), the number of times a method calls a block is solely determined by the method itself. So if you want `gsub` to yield only 5 times, the only way to do that is to pass in a regex which only matches the given strings five times.

Comment: Will that be the same if you use `gsub!` with `break`?

Comment: @sawa: If you call break in a `gsub!` block, the string will remain unchanged (at least in MRI 1.9.2). Presumably `gsub!` first creates a temporary string and then calls `replace` at the end (which will never happen if break is called).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `gsub()`? By its design, `gsub` is designed to replace all occurrences of something, so, right off the bat you're fighting it.

Use `sub` instead:

```
str = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
count = 5
count.times { str.sub!(/a/, 'x') }
p str
# >> "xxxxxaaaaa"

str = 'mississippi'
2.times { str.sub!(/s/, '5') }
2.times { str.sub!(/s/, 'S') }
2.times { str.sub!(/i/, '1') }
p str
# >> "m1551SSippi"
```

Comment: This was actually the solution Andrew presented in the original question. But this does not work when the replacement string matches the matching pattern; for example `sub!(/a/, 'cat')`.